# Twitter timelines for multiple users REST API

Tags: php, api, rest, twitter

I'm working on an app that will contain twitter timeline information for potentially hundreds of accounts. If the app scaled quickly, synchronous calls would be out of the question, so I'm investigating how to cache recent tweets for each account.

From doing research, it looks like I could:

- **Use the Search API**

Combine users into a string and use the Search API to retrieve recent tweets in a somewhat bulk scenario. I believe Twitter recommends a max of 10 keywords here...so its not all that "Bulk"

- **Use the REST API**

Retrieve feed for each user individually using GET statuses/user_timeline

Are these the only two options? With this, I could retrieve feeds for a max of 720 accounts per hour and cache them in a database. But, neither seem all that efficient.

Any advice on the best direction would be most appreciated!